# roslaunch error - "ERROR: cannot launch node of type"

Tags: roslaunch, catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using a launch file in groovy catkin package, roslaunch reports an error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nao_driver/nao_camera_both.py]: nao_driver
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ludo/workspace/catkin_ws/install/share
ROS path [2]=/home/ludo/workspace/catkin_ws/install/stacks
ROS path [3]=/home/ludo/workspace/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

The contents of the launch file

```
<node pkg="nao_driver" type="nao_camera_both.py" name="nao_camera_both" required="true" args="--pip=$(arg nao_ip) --pport=$(arg nao_port) fps=5" output="screen">
        <param name="camera_switch" type="int" value="1"/>
        <param name="fps" type="int" value="1"/>
                <!--
                Image quality constants
                        k960p = 3                # 1280*960
                        k4VGA = 3                # 1280*960
                        kVGA = 2                 # 640*480
                        kQVGA = 1                # 320*240
                        kQQVGA = 0               # 160*120
        -->
        <param name="quality" type="int" value="3"/>
        <param name="topCamParams" type="string" value="package://morris_simulation/config/topCamCalibSim.yml"/>
        <param name="bottomCamParams" type="string" value="package://morris_simulation/config/bottomCamCalib.yml"/>
  </node>
```

rosrun nao_driver nao_camera_both.py works well though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67488/roslaunch-error---%22error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type%22/) by [Martin Llofriu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3832/martin-llofriu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had a similar problem with a `rosbuild` package.
I was able to start the node via `rosrun`, but `roslaunch` wasn't able to launch my node, although the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH was set-up correctly. The launch-file worked already a few days ago.
I tried to locate my package with `rospack find [packagename]` and was able to find it at the assumed location.

I made a backup of the corrupted package, deleted it and created it again with `roscreate-pkg` in my workspace. After that I copied the old files (Source-Files, Manifest.xml, CMakeLists.txt) into the re-created package. Than I `rosbuild` the package and now everything seems to work again.

Cheers,
Georg

---

Originally posted by [marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3201/marvin/) with karma: 66 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Llofriu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3832/martin-llofriu/) on 2013-07-23**:
Thanks marvin! Actually regenerating the package made the difference. I could not find the factor that was making the difference. I had already tried erasing devel and install folders. Can someone explain how can regenerating the package make the difference?

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2016-06-04**:
this problem similar to mine,..  but in my case, i can launch other launcher in my package. just one package that has this kind of error. can you help? should i remake the package too?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the hydro's ROS version, with catkin use this command before `rosmake`:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

See the follwing [terminal's picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4eOiO9aBk6WNVliUktlTEpKcGs/view?usp=sharing):

--
Good Luck
S.Benaissa

---

Originally posted by [SBenaissa](https://answers.ros.org/users/24727/sbenaissa/) with karma: 21 on 2015-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-23**:
For future reference: don't use `rosmake` with a catkin workspace, use `catkin_make` instead.